# How to Optimize the following code in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if there is a better way to code the following:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ShtNm As String
Dim ScRow, ScCol, DbCol As Long

Sub LoadMonth()
With Sheet1
    .Calculate
    If .Range("B5").Value = "" Then AddNewSheet
    .Calculate
    ShtNm = .Range("ScYear").Value
    DbCol = .Range("B5").Value 'First Column
.Range("D6:J13,D15:J22,D24:J31,D33:J40,D42:J49,D51:J58,M4:M12").ClearContents

    For ScRow = 6 To 58 Step 9
        For ScCol = 4 To 10
            If .Cells(ScRow - 1, ScCol).Value = Empty Then GoTo NextCol
            .Cells(ScRow, ScCol).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Cells(2, DbCol).Value
            .Cells(ScRow + 1, ScCol).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Cells(3, DbCol).Value
            .Cells(ScRow + 2, ScCol).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Cells(4, DbCol).Value
            .Cells(ScRow + 3, ScCol).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Cells(5, DbCol).Value
            .Cells(ScRow + 4, ScCol).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Cells(6, DbCol).Value
            .Cells(ScRow + 5, ScCol).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Cells(7, DbCol).Value
            .Cells(ScRow + 6, ScCol).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Cells(8, DbCol).Value
            .Cells(ScRow + 7, ScCol).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Cells(9, DbCol).Value
            DbCol = DbCol + 1
        NextCol:
        Next ScCol
    Next ScRow
End With
End Sub
```

It works fine and does what I want, just takes a little long to run due to the loop. Wondering if there isn't a faster way to do what I'm asking it.

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe skip the `GoTo` altogether: `If Not .Cells(ScRow - 1, ScCol).Value = Empty Then` and copy multiple adjacent cells in one go `Range(.Cells(ScRow + 1, ScCol),.Cells(ScRow + 7, ScCol)).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Range(Cells(3, DbCol), Cells(9, DbCol)).Value`

Comment: This is almost perfect.  The copy though is giving me an application-defined or object-defined error. I updated it since it's part of a `with` to `Range(.Cells(ScRow + 1, ScCol), .Cells(ScRow + 7, ScCol)).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Range(.Cells(3, DbCol), .Cells(9, DbCol)).Value` any thoughts?

Comment: put a `.` in front of the `Range` also and the sheet name on the second range: `.Range(.Cells(ScRow + 1, ScCol), .Cells(ScRow + 7, ScCol)).Value = Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Range(Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Cells(3, DbCol), Sheets("" & ShtNm & "").Cells(9, DbCol)).Value`

Comment: missing the `.` *facepalm* -- thanks @Scott Craner

Comment: Always the `.` lol

Comment: @ScottCraner also that was perfect. really appreciate the advice/help!

Answer (score 0):

The For ScRow = 6 To 58 Step 9 iterates (6,15,24,33,42,51) => ((58 - 6) \ 9 + 1) => 6 times

For ScCol = 4 To 10 iterates (10-4+1) => 7 times

Total loops = 6 * 7 = 42,  so the DbCol at last will be DbCol+42

Read once in array all data from:

Sheets("" & ShtNm).Cells(2, DbCol)

to Sheets("" & ShtNm).Cells(9, DbCol+42)

since it appears to be a contiguous area.

Use the array data in the loop.